# simple square root function

Tags: python

Wrote a function to calculate the square root.

Magic from: https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/8

The result is almost always the same as `math.sqrt`. Difference percentage
is always around 10%. All difference (if any) is almost always in magnitude e-10.

How can the function be more accurate? Does is even need to be more accurate?

```
import math
from random import randint


def sqrt(n):
    x = 1  # initial guess
    h1, h2 = 0.0, 0.0 # history
    while True:
        # if answer or if number reappears
        if x*x == n or x == h1 or x == h2:
            return x
        h2 = h1
        h1 = x
        x = x - ((x*x - n) / (2*x)) # magic


if __name__ == "__main__":

    error_count = 0
    repeat = 300
    for _ in range(repeat):
        number = randint(0, 10000000000000)
        result = sqrt(number)
        math_result = math.sqrt(number)
        error = abs(result - math_result)
        if error:
            error_count += 1
        print(number, result, math_result, error)

    print()
    print(f"Errors: {error_count}")
    print(f"Percentage: {error_count/repeat:%}")
```

Comment: Does it even need to be more accurate? That's a question probably only you can answer. We don't know what you intend to do with it...

Comment: Using "==" in floating point arithmetic usually does not make sense. Additionally assuming that all digits returned by `math.sqrt(number)` are correct needs at least some justification. I think this is not true. So you should think about a better 'termination criterion' and a better way to check the quality of your result.